# Scala Android compile error - java heap space

Tags: android, scala, intellij-idea, proguard

I'm having some trouble getting IntelliJ to compile Scala for Android:

I'm using this guide: https://github.com/yareally/android-scala-intellij-no-sbt-plugin

And getting the following error:

[image: error]

I tried bumping my max heap sizes up to 2048 on all compilers (java, android dx, scala compiler), but doesn't change anything. Quits after about 3-4 seconds.

Any ideas?

(I'd like to avoid going the SBT route, at least for now, until I can get the more basic form of this working with just Proguard itself..)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it was a problem with the way I was setting up the scala JARs in IntelliJ. I didn't quite understand the distinction between compile-time and run-time JARs in the context of IntelliJ.  I was including multiple copies of `scala-library.jar` and `scala-compiler.jar` in various places.

I ended up having "scala-compiler" set up as a Global Library, with '-compiler.jar', '-reflect.jar', and '-library.jar' included within it.

I also have the scala-library.jar included under Libraries, and set up as a dependency in the `Modules -> <project name> -> Dependencies` section of the Project Structure window.

Had a few more problems with the 'android-scala-intellij-no-sbt-plugin' default proguard txt file. Had to add a bunch of -dontwarn lines for various parts of the scala library.

Compile time seems to be hovering around 26 seconds or so for a near-empty project.